# Angularjs resolve postPromise not running

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently working on a MEAN stack webapp, and postPromise doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to pull data from my db and download it as a CSV. After debugging a bit I narrowed it down to postPromise not being called (console.log('Look ma! I ran'); didn't run.) I have identical code running properly elsewhere in the app, so I'm a little stumped.

ui-router:

```
.state('adminDownload', {
            url: '/download',
            templateUrl: '../../views/admin-download.html',
            resolve: {
                postPromise: ['users', function(users){
                    console.log('look, ma! I ran!'); //is not called
                    return users.getAll();
                }]
            },
            onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
                if( ! auth.isLoggedIn()){
                  $state.go('adminLogin');
                }
            }]
        });
```

users factory:

```
    routerApp.factory('users', ['$http', function($http){
        var o = {
            users: []
        };

        o.getAll = function() {
            console.log('getAll was called');
            return $http.get('/users').success(function(data){
                angular.copy(data, o.users);
            });
        };

        o.create = function(user) {
            return $http.post('/users', user).success(function(data){
                o.users.push(data);
            });
        };

        return o;
    }]);

index.js, GET users:

/*GET users*/
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if(err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        console.log('get users called');//is not called
        res.json(users);

    });
});
```

CSV conversion code, incase that is actually the issue *lots of things are commented out for debugging purposes*:

```
routerApp.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', 'users', 'questions', function ($scope, users, questions){
    $scope.getData = function(){

        //get the results from user objects
        var data = [];

        console.log(users.users); //returns '[]'

        for (var i = 0; i < users.users.length; i++) {
            console.log('the loop got called');// is not called at users.users.length === 0
            console.log(users.users[i].results);
            $scope.data.push(users.users[i].results);
        }

        console.log('not in the loop any more :('); //is called

        // Convert Object to JSON
        var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(data);

        var convertToCSV = function(objArray) {
            var str = Papa.unparse(objArray);
            return str;
        }

        //console.log($scope.data);
        console.log(jsonObject); //returns '[]'
        //console.log(convertToCSV(jsonObject));

        //download .csv
        //window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(convertToCSV(jsonObject)));

    };
}]);
```

public/views/admin-greeting.html:

```
<div ng-app = 'routerApp', ng-controller = 'AdminCtrl'>
    <h1>Hello, Friend</h1>
    <button ng-click = 'getData()' href = 'data' download>Download Data</button>
</div>
<div ng-app = 'routerApp', ng-controller = 'AuthCtrl'>
    <button ng-click = 'logout()'>Logout</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The "tags" you select on your question are meant to be a reference to what the question is about, and not to refer to the other parts of your stack that the question has nothing to do with. Angular code only question. Angular only tags.

Comment: @Carriemf Any console error getting?

Comment: @VeeraBhadraRao, no errors, just added console output

Comment: I think this state is not calling, html is loading?

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao, the html is loading. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please add controller in state definition

```
    .state('adminDownload', {
        url: '/download',
        templateUrl: '../../views/admin-download.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        resolve: {
            postPromise: ['users', function(users){
                console.log('look, ma! I ran!'); //is not called
                return users.getAll();
            }]
        },
        onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
            if( ! auth.isLoggedIn()){
              $state.go('adminLogin');
            }
        }]
    });
```

Comment: @VeeraBhadraRao, it would make sense, but it doesn't appear to work. I'm still getting the same console output.

Comment: What console output you are getting?

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao, consolidated from the question: '[]' 'not in the loop anymore', '[]'

Comment: `users` factory calling? Please put console in users factory & check. And check the path of that factory.

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao, users factory does not call

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao, functionally yes. postPromise in the ui-router does not run and therefore `users.getAll()` is never called.